# C++ Exception Handling causing terminate

Tags: c++

We are facing a problem in c++ code.When an exception is thrown the
   process is getting terminated,but my code has proper exception
   handling.

```
   Core stack is below.
   ======================
   #0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
   #1  0x00489915 in raise () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
   #2  0x0048b379 in abort () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
   #3  0xf6a1fbdb in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   #4  0xf6a1d8f1 in __cxa_call_unexpected () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   #5  0xf6a1d926 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   #6  0xf6a1da6f in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Some of the forums showing that this might occur when there is a stack unwinding or exception raised when handling other exception.

Can you please suggest here to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you using threads? Are each of them correctly handling exceptions? Have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing what is happening at the time of the crash?

Comment: You'll have to at least find out *where* this is happening in order to get any help. Try setting your own terminate handle and place a breakpoint in it.

Answer (score 10):

Terminate can be called if:

- An exception is thrown while another exception is propagating
- An exception is thrown that violates an exception specification
- An exception is thrown and never caught

But your call stack also has `unexpected` =>`__cxa_call_unexpected ()`

To me this is an indication that an exception specification has been violated.
This calls unexpected() which by default calls terminate().

Answer (score 4):

Are you throwing an exception in any of your object destructors? A call to terminate generally happens in *nix systems when a new exception is thrown before the current exception is caught.

When an exception gets thrown the objects in your stack frame get destroyed as the stack unwinds. If any of these objects were to throw an exception during destruction, it confuses the exception handling mechanism as it has now two exceptions to catch, the original exception and the new one which gets thrown during the destruction of the object on the stack. So it issues a terminate and aborts.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be caused if/when cannot allocate memory for a dependent exception object which would be thrown. (I imagine this is rare. But is possible reason the app would terminate abnormally.)